# Spring data rest and spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am in the proces of creating simple CRUD program with Spring data rest [Spring data rest](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/),
but I have a problem with security configuration (example was taken from [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/rest/security).
I have a WebAppInitializer:

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{JpaRepositoryConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{CustRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return new Filter[]{ new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain")};
    }
}
```

I have a next crud repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.repository.annotation.RestResource;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
@RestResource(path = "products", rel = "products")
public interface ProductRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Product, Long> {

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    @Override
    Product save(Product s);

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    @Override
    void delete(Long aLong);
}
```

I have a next security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("greg").password("turnquist").roles("USER").and()
                .withUser("ollie").password("gierke").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .httpBasic().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/products").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/products/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH, "/products/**").hasRole("ADMIN").and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

I used next version of dependencies:

```
<java-version>1.7</java-version>
<spring-data-rest-version>1.0.0.RELEASE</spring-data-rest-version>
<spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
<org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
```

From project configured log4j I am getting these errors:

```
SEVERE: Error filterStart
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/admin] startup failed due to previous errors
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationCon
text - Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Dec 30 00:09:21 EET
2014]; root of context hierarchy 
......

DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter - Invokin
g destroy() on bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.au
thentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration'
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Re
trieved dependent beans for bean '(inner bean)': [(inner bean), productRepositor
y]
DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter - Invokin
g destroy() on bean with name 'securityConfig'
```

From tomcat 7.0.56 localhost log I also have these errors in the logs:

```
 SEVERE: Exception starting filter delegatingFilterProxy
    org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named      'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined
    at   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:278)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:194)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4830)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5510)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1879)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What is causing the errors in these logs?

Comment: Which problem do you have?

Comment: **Bean 'springSecurityFilterChain'** not found. Also at the moment not sure that my approach of connecting spring secure mechanism is a valid.

Comment: Looks like you didn't define that bean. Where's your Spring config file?